# DNS server cannot be reached

Tags: php, linux, server, dns, debian

I'm very new to coding and I'm trying to setup a csgo roulette site.
I've setup everything so far using filezilla, putty and Debian in a vm.
When I try to go to my site via the private ip this comes up: dns server could not be reached (translated from dutch). I'm sorry for asking something that is probably very easy to solve. May I ask you to keep answers relatively simple as I'm a complete noob since I started yesterday :)

Things you might want to know:
phpmyadmin works just fine. 
When I type in my ip i get redirected to this: http://www.ip/var/www/index.php?page=html.
I've tried a2enmod rewrite. That didn't solve it.
I've tried clearing browser history and cache, didn't solve it.

Ty for reading through :)

Comment: put your original domain name so that we can check your url

Comment: It's odd If you type an IP address you don't need DNS. did you type http://111.222.333.444/ or www.111.222.333.444?

Comment: Well It's just the IP i pulled from debian from wired connections. It's this: 192.168.110.130, but you can't connect to that right? So do I have to give out my public IP?

Comment: I tried both cyrus